# How to derive the variance of the nth generation of a branching process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, variance

Consider a branching Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$, where $X_0 = 1$ and the offspring distribution is given by $$p(0) = \frac 1 6, p(1) = \frac 1 2, p(2) = \frac 1 3.$$ The number of offspring produced by each individual is independent of the number of offspring produced by other individuals. Find the variance of the $n^{th}$ generation.

**My working**

Let $\mu$ and $\mu_n$ be the mean of the offspring distribution and the $n^{th}$ generation respectively. Similarly, let $\sigma^2$ and $\sigma^2_n$ be the variance of the offspring distribution and the $n^{th}$ generation respectively. From the definition of a random sum, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\mu_n & = \mu_{n - 1}\mu\\[1 mm]
& = \mu_0\mu^n\\[1 mm]
& = \mu^n
\end{aligned}$$

and

$$\begin{aligned}
\sigma^2_n & = \mu_{n - 1}\sigma^2 + \sigma^2_{n - 1}\mu^2\\[1 mm]
& = \mu^{n - 1}\sigma^2 + \sigma^2_{n - 1}\mu^2\\[1 mm]
& = \mu^{n - 1}\sigma^2 + \dots + \mu^{2n - 2}\sigma^2 + \sigma^2_0\mu^{2n}\\[1 mm]
& = \sigma^2\mu^{n - 1}(1 + \dots + \mu^{n - 1})\\[1 mm]
& = \sigma^2\mu^{n - 1}\left[\frac {\mu^n - 1} {\mu - 1}\right]
\end{aligned}$$

I believe my mean of the $n^{th}$ generation is correct, but I am unsure if I have solved the recurrence relation for the variance of the $n^{th}$ generation correctly. If I have gone wrong anywhere, any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. By [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance),
\begin{align*}
\sigma_n^2:=\mathrm{Var}(X_n)&=\mathrm{Var}(\mathbb E[X_n\mid X_{n-1}])+\mathbb E[\mathrm{Var}(X_n\mid X_{n-1})]\\[.4em]
&=\mu^2\,\sigma_{n-1}^2+\mathbb E[X_{n-1}]\,\sigma^2\\[.4em]
&=\mu^2\,\sigma_{n–1}^2+\mu^{n-1}\,\sigma^2\\[.4em]
&=\mu^2\left(\mu^2\,\sigma_{n-2}^2+\mu^{n-2}\,\sigma^2\right)+\mu^{n-1}\,\sigma^2\\
&=\ldots\\
&=\!\mu^{2n}\,\sigma^2_0+\sigma^2\sum_{i=n-1}^{2n-2}\mu^k\\[.4em]
&=\mu^{2n}+\frac{\mu^{2n-1}-\mu^{n-1}}{\mu-1}\sigma^2.
\end{align*}